# Upload image on ftp using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ftp, carrierwave

I implement image upload on ftp using carrierwave, and it is uploading image on ftp successfully.

Now problem is that when server is going to upload image on ftp, ftp is asking for authentication as no of times of images,I mean if I upload 2 images, It is going to ask 2 time for authentication.

And I dont want to ask authentication while images are uploading.

Here is my configuration for ftp:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.ftp_host = "ftp.hostname.com"
  config.ftp_port = 21
  config.ftp_user = "user_name"
  config.ftp_passwd = "password"
  config.ftp_folder = "/folder_name"
  config.ftp_url = "ftp://ftp.hostname.com/folder_name"
  config.ftp_passive = false
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you found a solution for this?